# Phpunit tests caching

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I am writing phpunit test in phpstorm, symfony2.

When the name of the test file is HomeSliderTest.php I am getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Acme\HardcoreBundle\Test\AcmeWebTestCase' not found in Acme/HardcoreBundle/Tests/Functional/HomeSliderTest.php on line 13
```

But when I change the name of the file in something else than everything is working correctly.

Does anyone have an idea what can be a problem?

```
namespace Acme\HardcoreBundle\Tests\Functional;
use Acme\HardcoreBundle\Test\AcmeWebTestCase;
class HomeSliderTest extends AcmeWebTestCase {...
```

I don't think that the problem is with code, because it is working when the name of the file is different, also the test is working on other machines.

Comment: Please show me the top of your `HomeSliderTest` class.

Comment: When you say rename the file, are you still ending it with 'Test.php' so that PHPUnit still recognizes it as a test file?  Or are you changing it to 'foo.php'?

Comment: Yes, I am ending it with the Test.php. I have a feeling that tests are cached some how but I don't know where.

Comment: How do you run your test? Do you pass a path to your phpunit.xml config? If no, it could be the reason, because you have there association with bootstrap file. Try run your tests like this: "phpunit -c app/ path/to/the/test"